# Is urllib2 slower than requests in python3

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I use python to simply call api.github.gist. I have tried urllib2 at first which cost me about 10 seconds!. The requests takes less than 1 senond

I am under a cooperation network, using a proxy. Do these two libs have different default behavior under a proxy?

And I use fiddler to check the network. In both situation, the http request finished in about 40ms. So where urllib spends the time on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely that DNS caching sped up the `requests`. DNS queries might take a lot of time in corporate networks, don't know why but I experience the same. The first time you sent the request with `urllib2` DNS queried, slow, and cached. The second time you sent the request with `requests`, DNS needed not to be queried just retrieved from the cache.

Clear up the DNS cache and change the order, i.e. request with `requests` first, see if there is any difference.